# Explicit examples of cyclic groups which product is (non-)cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm looking for explicit examples of cyclic groups $G_1,G_2,G'_1,G'_2$ such that the groups $G_1\times G_2$ is cyclic and $G'_1\times G'_2$ is non-cyclic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G_1'=G_2'=G_1=\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $G_2=\mathbb{Z}_3$. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ isn't cyclic group ($(1,0),(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are order $2$) and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_6 $ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the fact $\Bbb Z_m \times \Bbb Z_n$ is cyclic iff $(m,n)=1$